# React JS: Problems with passing my handler function with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three classes. In the first, I declare a handler-function (handleItemClick). I want to pass this function to the last class, a clickable list-item.

First class:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

...

    renderList: function() {
      return <SortableList topics={this.state.topics} whenItemClicked={this.handleItemClick} seminar={this.state.seminar} />
    },
  /* THE FUNCTION WHICH SHOULD BE INVOKED IN THE LIST ITEM */
    handleItemClick: function(type, item) {
        /** handle click **/
    },

...
});
```

The second is the list, creating list items. This class should get the handler function from the first class and pass it to the third.

sortable-list.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var Sortable = require('sortablejs');
var SortableMixin = require('sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin');
var ListItem      = require('./list-item');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins: [SortableMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items : this.props.topics
        };
    },
    handleClick: function(type, item) {
        // invoke whenItemClicked of the previous class
        this.props.whenItemClicked(type, item);
    },
    handleSort: function (/** Event */evt) {
     /**/
    },

    render: function() {
        return <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked mail-nav" style={{marginTop: '0px'}}>{
            this.state.items.map(function (topic) {
                return <ListItem whenItemClicked= {this.handleClick} type={"topic"} item={topic}  key={topic.id}  />                
            })
        }</ul>
    }
});
```

And finally the class list-item.jsx where clicks can appear.

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    // this should invoke the handleClick of sortable-list.jsx
    this.props.whenItemClicked(this.props.type, this.props.item);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <li>
      <a onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.props.selected ? "selected" : ""}>
        {this.props.item.title}
      </a>
    </li>
  }
});
```

When I click on a list item, the function `handleClick` in list-item.jsx is called. But the call of `this.props.whenItemClicked` fails (is undefined) for some reason.
When I debug the code, even in sortable-list.jsx in line `return <ListItem whenItemClicked= {this.handleClick} type={"topic"} item={topic}  key={topic.id}  />` the handleClick is undefined.

I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) by default `this` refers to global scope (in browser it is `window`), so when you call `this.handleClick` in `.map` it will be `undefined` because in `window` there is not function `handleClick`, pass second argument to you `.map` that will set `this` in callback, like this

```
this.state.items.map(function (topic) {
  return <ListItem whenItemClicked= {this.handleClick} type={"topic"} item={topic}  key={topic.id}  />                
}, this)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really the problem. This already took me several hours!